# Lua pattern to select particular string followed by any word

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

Can anyone please let me know why I am not able to select `CWIND7x32\ab_c1` in the below code?

```
s="[cC][wW][iI][nN]7[xX]32"
local p= (tostring(s).."\\([%%w_]+)?")
local c = "##\\##"
print(p)
tstr = "Pattern CWINd7x32\\ab_c1 is valid"
print(tstr)
res=string.gsub(tstr,p,c)
print(res)
```

I want a pattern to select any word which is in the format CWINDX32\any word, where CWINDX32 should be case insensitive word.

Note that the word can have alpha-numeric characters and underscore only and may be terminated by whitespace or ; or , or :

**Example:**

Pattern CWINd7x32\ab_c1 is valid -> Pattern ##\## is valid

Pattern cWIND7x32\efg; is valid -> Pattern ##\##; is valid

Pattern CWIND7X32\random_user, is valid -> Pattern ##\##, is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you missed `[dD]` in the pattern, which I guess is a typo.

There are still some other problems.

- `?` in Lua patterns only applies to a single character, so
  `"\\([%%w_]+)?"` is invalid.
- `%%` is the escaped `%` character, `[%%w_]` matches a `%` character, a `w` or an underscore `_`, wihch is not what you expected.

The fixed pattern is `[cC][wW][iI][nN][dD]7[xX]32\[%w_]+`.